# MobileFirst 8 Android APP cannot connect to MobileFirst server after direct update

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

Here's the scenario:

1. Android device install WebResource Encrypt MFP APP.
2. Direct update web resource.
3. Restart this APP [ onDestory() -> onCreate() ]
4. Fail to connect MobileFirst8 Server

The logcat info:
[image]

We enable the follow features:

1. Certificate pinning
2. WebResource encrypt(mfpdev app webencrypt).

> MobileFirst server version :
>
> 8.0.0.00-20170901-1903
>
> Cordova MFP plugin version :
>
> 1. cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017082110
> 2. cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017082110

---

### Update 1:

Even if we did not Direct Update web resource, just restart this app will fail to connect MobileFirst server.

The test scenario:

1. cordova prepare
2. mfpdev app webencrypt (with certificate pinning)
3. debug on android device
4. first run works fine. but fail to connect when reload this app

Here's the device log when APP restart:
[image]

MFP server version : 8.0.0.00-20170901-1903

mfpdev-cli version : 8.0.0-2017080206

cordova-plugin-mfp version : 8.0.2017090705

device info : Android 7.0

Test project source code : [GitHub link](https://github.com/DannyYang/MobileFirstPMR/tree/master)

Comment: If you do not enable webresource encyrption, does it work for you? Or is it only when webresource encryption is enabled?

Comment: without web resources encryption,it works

Comment: For good measure, can you try with the latest client side plugin - 8.0.2017090705

Comment: We have tried the latest client side plugin. but it still fail to connect MFP server(check Update 1)

Comment: Can you please open a PMR with IBM to get this investigated. Quote this SO post as reference

Comment: We have opened the PMR. Thank you.

Comment: We also publish our test project to github. plz check update 1 link. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case has been fixed via [PI88636](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/10/30/8-0-ifix-release/)

Use cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017102115 to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if the certificate you are looking for is available in the 'certificates' folder. The error message suggests that the certificate does not exist in the specified location.

Comment: We are sure that the cert file does exist and the path is correct.
After direct update still work fine. But will fail to connect MFP server when this APP restart

Answer (score 0):

The case of direct update not working when WebResourcesEncryption is enabled, has been fixed via [APAR PI84522](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/09/05/8-0-ifix-release/):

Install the latest iFix to resolve the issue.

Comment: We are using this fixed pack. but after directUpdate and restart this APP will fail to connect MFP server

Comment: Do you see the problem immediately after direct update? ie, after direct update the application reloads on its own. Do you see the issue immediately after? Or it starts only after you kill and start the application? 
If certificate pinning is not enabled, do you see issues with connection after direct update?

Comment: It failed to connect only kill and start the application. If certificate pinning is not enable, it works.